# Why does this rsync command produce a list with each file followed by: Permission denied

Tags: rsync, permission-denied

I finally put this together after much time on the different forums...

```
rsync -avh -n --files-from=<(find ./ -type f -mtime -13 -not -path './moviesseries/*' -not -path './Library/*' -exec {} \;) /home/frazelle09/Documents /home/frazelle09/Documents/test
```

I wanted to begin to use rsync after many years of using other different backup programs which have produced many backups.  i didn't want to have to do another "complete" backup again using rsync, i just wanted to start using rsync on the most "recent" (last 13 days or whatever) files, so i had to come up with this complicated rsync which also uses the find command.

So,it finally produces an output of 15 some files, but each file is followed by Permission Denied. I wonder if this is a result of using the "-n" function with rsync.

The following is a partial listing...

````
building file list ... find: ‘./Asamblea_Mexicali/Correspondencia/2019/Bienvenida.odt’: Permission denied
find: ‘./Asamblea_Mexicali/Creyentes/Contactos_Son_Sin_Convencion_Regional.ods’: Permission denied
find: ‘./Asamblea_Mexicali/Creyentes/Elecciones/Convencion_Regional_2020/Instructivo para las Convenciones Regionales 2019.pdf’: Permission denied
find: ‘./Asamblea_Mexicali/Creyentes/Elecciones/Convencion_Regional_2020/Machote_carta_invitacion_convencion_regional_en_mexicali.odt’: Permission denied
find: ‘./Asamblea_Mexicali/Creyentes/Elecciones/Convencion_Regional_2020/Consideraciones para las Convenciones Regionales Bahá'ís 2019.pdf’: Permission denied
find: ‘./Asamblea_Mexicali/Creyentes/Elecciones/Convencion_Regional_2020/Reporte de la Convención Regional 2019.pdf’: Permission denied
/.~lock.Contactos_Son_Sin_Convencion_Regional.ods#’: Permission denied
find: ‘./Asamblea_Mexicali/Creyentes/Elecciones/Convencion_Regional_2020/Las elecciones bahá'ís .odt’: Permission denied
find: ‘./nur_photo.odt’: Permission denied

sent 18 bytes  received 12 bytes  20.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)```

Have a great evening!  :)
````

Comment: `find ... -exec {} \;` will try to *execute* each of the found files, and I suspect most of them aren't executable (and don't have execute permission set). I suspect you want to print their names instead, but you'd probably be better using a couple of `--exclude` options to `rsync`, and setting the other options correctly so `rsync` can figure out for itself which files need to be updated.

Comment: Thank you Gordon.  i changed this a little.  Since i'm still learning, i didn't realize that -exec wants to execute a command, so i provided the copy command...

rsync -avh -n --files-from=<(find ./ -type f -mtime -13 -not -path './moviesseries/*' -not -path './Library/*' -exec cp -t {} \;) /home/frazelle09/Documents /home/frazelle09/Documents/test

but now, instead of Permission denied, i get... cp: target './nur_photo.odt' is not a directory - lol.  Close, but not yet.

Have a great evening!  :)

Comment: Ack, please be very careful here; putting these commands together wrong can lead to deleting the files you're trying to back up! `cp` will, under some circumstances, overwrite one file with another, and it won't even tell you anything happened. You don't want `cp` here, since you want `rsync` to do the copying. Again, `rsync` can do pretty much what you want all by itself.

Comment: Dear Gordon.  You are the winner!  [code]rsync -avh --files-from=<(find ./ -type f -mtime -15 -not -path './moviesseries/*' -not -path './Library/*') /home/frazelle09/Documents /home/frazelle09/Documents/test[/code]  

as you can see, i deleted the part containing the "cp" command and just left the rest.  It successfully found the files and copied them into the "test" folder, preserving the file structure as well as the time and dates.  Yea!!

Have a super evening!  :)

Comment: Now, if i could only find a way to mark this thing as SOLVED...